# Handling missing data in prediction data set because event has not occured

Tags: prediction, missing-data

I am building a model to determine if a student will pass or fail a particular class.  I am using the RandomForest algorithm.  Apart from features such as student's age, SAT score, etc, I can use other "time dependent" features such as attendance and quiz scores.  I call these "time dependent" because at the start of the semester, these features will not be available for students in the prediction data set.

Any ideas on how such features can be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could train the model with and without the "time dependent" features.

Compare the performance of the model with "time dependent" features to without. Is there a big difference? If "time dependent" features do not significantly improve your model then they can be excluded all-together.

Also try a model with only "time dependent" features. If this model way out-performs the model without "time dependent" features, there may be no use in trying to predict the student's performance without SOME class data (quiz/test scores...),

If the "time dependent" features make a difference, keep both models to use for prediction at different points during the class. The model trained without using the "time dependent" features would be used for prediction before the start of the semester. You could then, say, train a model including only the first quiz score. This could be used after the first quiz, and so on for following tests.

This may be obvious already, but putting 0s in place of the "time dependent" variables where it is unavailable could lead to erroneously low predicted class performance.